# R: DuckDB DBconnect is very slow - Why?

Tags: r, sqlite, duckdb

I have a *.csv file containing columnar numbers and strings (13GB on disk ) which I imported into a new duckdb (or sqlite) database and saved it so I can access it later in R. But reconnecting duplicates it and is very slow, is this wrong?

From within R, I am doing the following:

```
library(duckdb)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

#Create the DB
con <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), "FINAL_data.duckdb")

#Read in the csv
duckdb_read_csv(con, "data", "FINAL_data_new.csv")
```

I then close R and restart it to see if it has worked:

#This is super slow (about 10minutes), because it looks like it's writing the DB again somewhere. But why?

```
con <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), "FINAL_data.duckdb")
```

NB. I've added sqlite as a tag because I don't think this is particular to duckdb

Comment: Which part is slow? If it is `dbConnect` this is particular to either your setup or the `duckdb` package. It as always been blazing fast to connect to any SQL-type database I've ever worked with using `odbc` and `DBI`.

Comment: Ohh that's really interesting... the dbconnect is super slow in RStudio. from a terminal window, it's lightning fast... How strange. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried updating rstudio? I have no obvious reasons.

Comment: Or maybe it is the startup from rstudio that is slow, because you have a lot of large variables that are saved from prior sessions. `rm(list =ls()) ; save.image() ` could fix that.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you. Just to double check, do you use tbl(con, "data)  as the object to query?

Comment: I wasn't starting RStudio again but just disconnecting and reconnecting from the DB but doing rm(list =ls()) has solved the problem, thank you very much. It's very strange. What's the difference between dbReadTable(con, "data") and tbl(con,"data")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The slowdown you experienced is due to the database checkpointing on startup. This has been fixed on the master branch already.